# Assign to my UIButton what the editButtonItem from the NavigationBar does

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a TableView on my View. I somehow do not have a Navigation bar. I only have UIButtons and I want one of my buttons to do exactly what the editButtonItem.

How must I proceed to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Where you create your button:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:selector(toggleEditMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then add the method:

```
-(void)toggleEditMode:(id)sender {
    // Change the tableview's editing state to the opposite of the current state
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.editing animated:YES];

    // change the title of the button
    UIButton *editButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (self.editing) {
        [editButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [editButton setTitle@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a target to that button – i.e.

```
@selector(editButtonPressed:)
```

Then in editButtonPressed: use the function

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

i think that'll work...

Comment: You may want to do `[self.tableView setEditing:!self.editing animated:YES]`, that way you can use one method to toggle back and forth between editing states.

Comment: thx jmont & gordon, could you provide an example code please? I'm new to iphone programming

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials online. i.e.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-creating-basic-buttons

google is your friend.

Comment: Posted the code snippet as a separate answer for formatting reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, i'll give a try tomorrow :D

Answer (score 1):

The super quick way with a Storyboard and IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)editTap:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
  BOOL isEditing = self.tableView.editing;
  [self.tableView setEditing:!isEditing animated:YES];
  sender.title = isEditing ? @"Edit" : @"Done";
}
```